# Mongoose authenticating with keyfile

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo replica set with 3 members and they are using keyFile authorisation. I am using Mongoose and from their docs could not find a way to authenticate via a keyFile.

Does Mongoose support it ? if so, how do I specify a keyFile while authenticating ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not authenticate your client via a keyFile. You can setup SSL and use x509 to authenticate. However, a keyFile is for authentication between replication set members. For authentication you must create a user and require authentication in your mongodb config. The user is local to that database in which it is created. x509 requires some extra steps to correlate the key/cert to a given user.

If you have no need for SSL, I'd recommend just creating an admin user for the entire database, then creating a user for the database you're trying to access in your app.